# Docker unable to start

Tags: docker

When I try to do `docker run` I get this:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
```

So I looked here https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1010 and I tried this:

```
docker-machine env default
```

But I'm getting:

```
Error checking TLS connection: exit status 126
```

So I looked here https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/453 and I tried this:

```
docker-machine rm default
```

Now I'm getting:

```
Error removing host "default": exit status 126
```

So what is the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: On which OS are you?

Comment: sudo docker ps works?

Comment: No. "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?"

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be caused by a few things:

1. Permissions - your user does not have the correct access rights to talk to the socket. Runner `sudo usermod -aG docker YOUR-USER` replacing YOUR-USER to the correct value. Note you will need to completely log out and log back in again for the changes to take effect
2. Your shell env is not set correctly with docker-machine - Each tab you open in terminal needs to connect to the correct machine if you are to use it correctly try running `eval $(docker-machine env default)` and then running some docker commands to see if that resolves your issues
3. Try regenerating the TLS certs for the machine and repeating step 2 - I noticed there was a TLS error. Sometimes the certs for connecting to the daemon can become invalid. Regenerate the certs by running `docker-machine regenerate-certs default`.

Update me with your progress and I'll be happy to help troubleshoot further.

Hope this helps

Dylan

### Edit

1. Try creating a fresh docker machine with `docker-machine create -d YOUR-PROVIDER YOUR-NAME` and seeing if it is a machine specific issue